# Connect vscode to my remote server using FTP-SIMPLE extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I want to connect to my server using ftp-simple extension in vscode. But when i try to do ftm-simple: confi, i am getting the following error.

Running the contributed command: 'ftp.config' failed.

Can someone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 1):

[You can instal other version for example 0.6.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsEqQ.png)

Comment: Hey guys, it worked when i degraded the version to 0.5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Open configuration file and add all the related configuration well and it should work.